# Matplotllib: set "bad" colour in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm having problems setting the color of `np.nan` values in my data set.
I already managed to get the `camp.set_bad` working in `imshow` plots but it does not work in `plt.scatter`.

Anyways, my main goal is assigning a specific colour to bad values.

This is how I though it would work (but it does not ;-)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 20
x = y = np.linspace(1, 10, n)
c = np.random.random_sample((n,))
c[4] = np.nan
c[8:12] = np.nan

cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
cmap.set_bad(color='black', alpha = 1.)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=200, cmap=cmap)
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: Scatter plot with "bad" values]

Of course, I could divide the dataset into two separate sets and overplot them, but I'm quite sure there is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Just a guess, but the docs for `plt.scatter` say that "cmap is only used if c is an array of floats", whereas a similar statement is not made about `plt.imshow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no black color in cmap `plasma`.

Array `c` has to store indexes of colors which your select from current color map `cmap`. If your set `c` as `NaN` it means you do not get a object for these indices (4 and 8:12) on a scatter-plot.

The first variant is to set color for selected indices manually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
n = 20
x = y = np.linspace(1, 10, n)
c = np.random.random_sample((n,))
#c[4] = np.nan
#c[8:12] = np.nan
c[4]=c[8:12]=0 # first color use to mark 4 and 8:12 elements
cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=200, c=c, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The second variant is to draw two scatter-plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 20
x = y = np.linspace(1, 10, n)
c = np.random.random_sample((n,))
c[4] = np.nan
c[8:12] = np.nan
cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')

# plot good values
indices = ~np.isnan(c)
plt.scatter(x[indices], y[indices], s=200, c=c[indices], cmap=cmap)
# plot bad values
plt.scatter(x[~indices], y[~indices], s=200, c='k')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, the second approach is actually what I'm doing currently. So no easier solution yet. Thanks anyways!

Comment: It is impossible because the plasma color map does not include black color and `c` has to store number of a color from a color map.